# Как разложить List<Some> в Map

Tags: java, map, лямбда-выражение

Есть такой класс

```
class Some {
S s;
String s1;
B b;
}

class B {
List<C> listOfC;
}

class C {
List<D> listOfD;
}

class D {
Long l;
}

class S {
String string;
}
```

Подскажите как с помощью Java 8 разложить в такую структуру

```
Map<S string, Map<String s1, Map<Long l, List<D>>>>
```

Comment: Вы не можете одни типы разложить в другой тип в Java. Если речь о перегоне данных из одной коллекции в другую, то вам надо показать ваши коллекции и ваши попытки решить проблему самостоятельно.

Comment: Правильная запись будет такой: `Map<String, Map<String, Map<Long, List<D>>>>`.

Comment: Непонятно, какую именно `l` надо использовать. Первую в списке? Или зачем класть её в виде ключа в мапу со значениями в виде списков?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы все `D` были разложены по `l`

Answer (score 0):

А попробуйте этим алгоритмом вашу супер-структуру разобрать:

```
List<Some> someList = ...;

Map<String, Map<String, Map<Long, List<D>>>> items = new HashMap<>();

for (Some some : someList) {
    Map<String, Map<Long, List<D>>> sub = items.computeIfAbsent(some.s.string, k -> new HashMap<>());
    Map<Long, List<D>> sub2 = sub.computeIfAbsent(some.s1, k -> new HashMap<>());

    for (C c : some.b.listOfC) {
        for (D d : c.listOfD) {
            sub2.computeIfAbsent(d.l, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(d);
        }
    }
}
```